# Roll Up Summary Field Does Populate Email Alert

Tags: email-alert, roll-up-summary

I have a roll up summary field that does not populate during an email alert.

I have tried setting a delay of one hour (allow the field to populate before the email alert fires out), but still the field does not populate in the email alert.

Checked FLS, among other things, no luck.

Has anyone else encountered this issue?

Comment: so you have a ROS field.  You send an email alert, including the ROS field, and you see..what?  You see nothing?  You see a zero?  You see the prior value?  Is this a html email template or a visualforce email template?  I've never had issue w/ this, though you can try to force recalculation of a ROS field which could perhaps help.  Click edit - Force a mass recalculation of this field

Comment: @gorav No value, returns null. HTML Template, recalculation does not work. :(

Comment: But it has a value when displayed on the page?  How are you sure that the field has a value?

Comment: @gorav Thanks for your help. The detail page shows a value and my queries show a value. It is weird, perhaps because the field is from a managed package?

Comment: Are you including the object name?  I dont have a managed object + managed ROS field to test on, but testing on a managed ROS field on a standard object, you do need to include the object name

so this does not work : {!npe01__LastDonationDate__c}
and this does work : {!Account.npe01__LastDonationDate__c}

Comment: great, glad it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Object` name needs to be included in the email template `merge field`.

If you add a field using the email template generation UI, Salesforce does that automatically.

[image: addFieldViaUI]

If you copy the field's API name from the object details page, then you need to prepend the object API name manually.

[image: objectDetailPage]